# react-cropper initialize from api

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i am using **react-cropper** package for building website.

```
import React from 'react';
import Cropper from 'react-cropper';
...

export default MyComponent() {
  ...
  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState(null);
  const [cropper, setCropper] = useState(null);
  ....
  
  useEffect(() => (
    ....

    const profile = api.get('/profile');
    setImageSrc(profile.src);

    ....
  ), [])

  return (
    ...

    <Cropper
      style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}
      guides={false}
      initialAspectRatio={16 / 9}
      src={previewImage}
      ref={(crop) => setCropper(crop)}
    />
    ...
  )
}
```

Here, when I use static image path in useEffect, I can see initialized image.

```
setImageSrc("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/roadmanfong/react-cropper/master/example/img/child.jpg);
```

But when I load image from api, I can't see initialized image.

I hope your co-operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `api.get()` is an asynchronous function and when you set the `imageSrc` state, `profile` is just a pending promise and `profile.src` is `undefined`. If you set your state to `undefined`, you can't see the initialised image.

To solve this, you can either use promises, or async/await. Check the snippet below where I wrap the API's `get` method in an async function and use await to wait for the result before it's passed to `setImageSrc`:

```js
useEffect(() => (
  // ....

  const fetchProfile = async () => {
    const profile = await api.get('/profile');
    setImageSrc(profile.src);
  };
  fetchProfile();

  // ....
), [])
```